# ASP.NET Refresh page on timer; query database in between timer

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, timer, asp.net-webpages

'I have a solution in my head, but am unsure if it is possible in ASP.NET. I don't have a lot of experience with timers. My idea is as follows:

```
'Code Behind
'At the end of the timer(lets say 1 minute)
    Dim qry = "SELECT ISNULL(Value, '') FROM Database.Schema.Table WHERE 
               Column = @Something"

    'set up sql connection and execute query
    Using sqlcon as new SQLConnection() 'Don't focus on this part
        Using sqlcmd = New SQLCommand(sqlcon,qry) 'Don't focus on this part either syntax is probably incorrect
            sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("Something", VarChar)
            sqlcmd.Parameters("Something").Value = "Row Found"

            'Refresh page; assign label control on .aspx page to value of returned query 
            'SafeToString() is a function that will safely return a string whether the value is some string, DBNULL, Nothing, or ''

             lblString.Text = SafeToString(sqlcmd.ExecuteScalar())
        End Using
    End Using
```

I want to be able to do this while maintaining scrolls position as well. So I don't interrupt the work/browsing the user is doing.

Thank you all for your input!

Comment: It's hard to understand what you want..Is it that you want to refresh your form ?

Comment: You're basically talking about AJAX, i.e. updating part of the page without refreshing the page.

Comment: @zackraiyan I want to refresh the page on a timer e.g. 1 minute, without affecting the page. In other words, I want to refresh the page without the user noticing. Even more specifically, I want to refresh a single column in a databound repeater on the page on a timer seamlessly, without the user noticing.

Comment: @jmcilhinney But can I query a database on a timer with AJAX? I have never used AJAX to query a database, but do have experience with it.

Comment: umm...i guess AJAX will do the work

Comment: @zackraiyan Do you know of any example? I'm not able to google a problem like this. Maybe it's my wording and my Google Fu is not great, lol.

Comment: maybe this would help [link](http://www.ashishblog.com/calling-database-using-jquery-ajax-and-asp-net/)

Comment: @zackraiyan Yes, that shows how to bind controls via a sqlconnection. I can do that already, my question is more about the timer and updating the bind on an interval without the user noticing. I want to refresh a single field in a table on an interval with no interruption to the users experience.

Comment: actually i haven't worked much with AJAX...but don't worry, i'll try to post a better answer soon

Answer (score 1):

I had never used WebForms (which I assume this question is about) but regardless I think you're approaching the problem in a wrong way. A page refresh is destructive and distracting, when a page is refreshed the browser has to fetch the page again (this includes all assets and scripts) and re-render the page.

## Client-side implementation

So the solution must be implemented at the client side and not require a full page refresh, this can be achieved using `Javascript` and [ajax](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp)(from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming))) requests. 
In short `ajax` is a mechanism for issuing additional requests to a web server while the page is loaded and running. That way you can fetch new data in the background without interrupting the user.

1. When the page loads set up a timeout or an [interval](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp):

   ```
   let intervalId = setInterval(updateFromServer, 1000);
   ```

   This interval will call `updateFromServer` every 1 second (1000ms).
2. Define the function `updateFromServer`:

   ```
   function updateFromServer() {
       let newData = fetchData();
       updateData(newData);
   }
   ```

   This function is call by the interval we've set up and does 2 things: it fetches new data from the server and pushes it to the DOM using `updateData`.
3. You can use ajax (for example with jquery) to fetch the data:

   ```
   function fetchData() {
       return $.ajax({ 
           type: "GET", 
           url: remote_url, 
           async: false 
       }).responseText;
   }
   ```

   This is where ajax comes in, the above lines use [jquery ajax api](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to send a `GET` request to the server at the url `remote_url`. The browser issues the request and waits for the server to respond.
4. And finally update the page (again I'm using jquery):

   ```
   function updateData(newData) {
       $('#data-el').text(newData)
   }
   ```

   Again we are using jquery here (you can use pure javascript though) to find an element with the ID `data-el` and setting its content to `newData`.

Comment: So will this method cause no disruption to the user?

Edit: Sorry, I am unable to test this at the moment and am just trying to get a clear picture before I attempt the suggestions posted.

Comment: but won't ajax do the same ?

Comment: Since I used synchronous ajax in my example the request to the server may cause the page to hang while data is being fetched, other than that no.

Comment: Would you be able to explain these lines of code more?
function fetchData() {
    return $.ajax({ 
        type: "GET", 
        url: remote_url, 
        async: false 
    }).responseText;
}

Can I query a database for my data instead of getting it from the page?

Comment: I'll add a bit more information for future reference but I'd suggest you read about `ajax` requests in detail and if there are sill things unclear to you open another question.

Comment: @MatanShahar Thank you! Much appreciated!

Comment: @MatanShahar,we've been suggesting ajax till now...So ur answer is not entirely relevant.So, if you can , please show some reference/example or ajax

Answer (score 1):

Look up `Page Methods`. JS can call a code-behind method which can return a value to the js method which can then update the page. The code behind method cannot access the page directly, only return a value to the js method.

Comment: Now I like the sound of that. I will do some research and see if I can find anything. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ex: https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2007/08/28/creating-and-consuming-aspnet-ajax-page-methods.aspx